# Create a Javascript function from this jQuery snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following code, it is working, but I'd like to "automatize" it with a javascript function, so I won't have to write it over and over again.

```
$("#portfolio").waypoint(function() {

    $('.portfolio-item').eq(0).css("animation-delay","0.0s");
    $('.portfolio-item').eq(1).css("animation-delay","0.3s");   
    $('.portfolio-item').eq(2).css("animation-delay","0.6s");
    $('.portfolio-item').eq(3).css("animation-delay","0.9s");
    $('.portfolio-item').eq(4).css("animation-delay","1.2s");
    $('.portfolio-item').eq(5).css("animation-delay","1.5s");
    $('.portfolio-item').eq(6).css("animation-delay","1.8s");
    $('.portfolio-item').eq(7).css("animation-delay","2.1s");
    $('.portfolio-item').eq(8).css("animation-delay","2.4s");

    $('.portfolio-item').addClass('animated fadeInUp'); 

}, { offset: 400});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your own code that you tried to do what you need.

Comment: Just put it inside a function definition, what's the problem?

Comment: And use a loop for all that repeated animation-delay code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to SidCool's answer would be to use jQuery `each` to prevent using `eq` :

```
$('#portfolio').waypoint(function(){
    var $items=$('.portfolio-item');
    $items.each(function(i){
        $(this).css('animation-delay', (i*0.3)+"s");
    });
    $items.addClass('animated fadeInUp');
}, {offset: 400});
```

Though, I just realized that he suggested it earlier. Credits to him :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, but worth giving a try:

```
$("#portfolio").waypoint(function() {
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++){
            var j = (i*0.3)+"s";
            $('.portfolio-item').eq(i).css("animation-delay",j);
    }
    $('.portfolio-item').addClass('animated fadeInUp'); 

}, { offset: 400});
```

Comment: I am glad!  You can make it more dynamic by using the each function of jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I thinked about it but wasn't sure about how to use it.. If you have a minute, can you provide a sample with it?

Comment: @Frederik.L has given a more elegant solution.  Please accept his answer as the correct one by clicking the tick symbol below the voting links against his response.

Comment: @SidCool Thanks! Yours is good too, more efficient than mine, but efficiency always come with the price of scalability.

Comment: That's right @Frederik.L, but given the number of elements, I would rather go for a cleaner and more elegant approach than a supposedly efficient one  :)  So your solution is better in this case.